# Let $f(2^{-n}) = 3^{-n}$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Where is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

I interpreted $f$ to be:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}3^{-n} & \text{ , if }x=2^{-n}\\0 & \text{ , otherwise }\end{cases} $$

I was shown the wrong answer for how to prove it's differentiable at $0$ and now I'm completely stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{f(h) -f(0)}{h}\right|\leqslant \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{-\log_2 h} \to 0$$